# Segmentation fault with array indexing in Fortran

Tags: arrays, indexing, fortran

Let `A` and `I` be an arrays of the integer type with dimension N. In general, `I` is a permutation of the integers `1:N`. I want to do `A(1:N) = A(I(1:N))`. For small `N` this works fine, but I got `Segmentation fault` when `N` is large. 
Here is an example of what I actually did:

```
integer N
integer,dimension(:),allocatable::A,I
N = 10000000
allocate(A(N))
allocate(I(N))
A = (/ (i,i=1,N) /)
I = (/ (N-i+1,i=1,N) /)
A(1:N) = A(I(1:N))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `i` in your case is an array, and you are using that as a loop variable? Is that even possible?

Comment: For what it's worth, using a dedicated `ii` variable in the implied do loops, the code executes fine even for `N` = 100M (gfortran v.5.4).

Comment: Just to make this explicit, Fortran is case insensitive so `I` and `i` refer to the same variable.

Comment: My gfortran gives `Error: Loop variable at (1) cannot be a sub-component
` and does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `A(I(1:N))` is valid syntax, at least in my testing (`gfortran 4.8`, `ifort 16.0`, `pgfortran 15.10`). One problem is that `i` and `I` are the same thing, and the array `I` cannot be used in an implied do as you are doing. Replacing it with `j` yields a program that runs for me:

```
program main
   implicit none

   integer :: N, j
   integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: A, I

   ! -- Setup
   N = 10000000
   allocate(A(N),I(N))
   A = (/ (j,j=1,N) /)
   I = (/ (N-j+1,j=1,N) /)

   ! -- Main operation
   A(1:N) = A(I(1:N))

   write(*,*) 'A(1): ', A(1)
   write(*,*) 'A(N): ', A(N)

end program main
```

As to why you're seeing a segmentation fault, I guess you're running out of memory when the array sizes get huge. If you're still having trouble, though, I suggest the following.

Instead of using `A(1:N) = A(I(1:N))`, you really should be using a loop, such as

```
! -- Main operation
do j=1,N
   Anew(j) = A(I(j))
enddo
A = Anew
```

This is more readable and easier to debug moving forward.

Comment: your last loop is not correct as you'll be accessing changed values of `A` on the r.h.s.  I think you need to first make a copy to use a loop like that.

Comment: that's better. I'd guess `A(1:N) = A(I(1:N))` causes the compiler to make a copy behind the scenes anyway..

Comment: On my linux box with ifort-16, the above program segfaults with N > ~4 * 10^6 because its stack size is about 10 MB. I guess ifort is making a temporary array for whole-array assignment, which might lead to the segfault. This does not happen with gfortran, but with `-fstack-arrays` it again gives segfault (using mac mini with 8.5 MB stack size). (Because the OP is saying that "the code works for small N", maybe `i` and `I` are simply typos...?)

Comment: Right. Specifically allocating a copy (which would be done for `Anew`) will make the process more transparent and put it on the heap by default.

Comment: Sorry, `I` and `i` are typo... Make a copy of A solves the problem. This may be a memory problem. I didn't try with gfortran, but I used ifort on different computer, and larger memory allowed larger N. Thanks All.